# working os.path.exist command

Tags: python

I create a folder with name InputData by hand. But I want to create a folder automatically inside InputData folder. I want to know the significance of os.path.exist in the following code.

```
`list =[1.0,2.0]
for hc in list:
    if not os.path.exists('InputData/'+str(hc)):
        os.mkdir('InputData/'+str(hc))`
```

Comment: Did you read the docs? Or the name of the method? What do you *think* it's doing, and have you tested that assumption?

Comment: Did you try what happens if you remove that part? What happens if you execute the code twice without that part?

Comment: The purpose of the `os.path.exists` call is to introduce a race condition (i.e. a bug) into your code.

Comment: I read that os.path.exist is used to check path and it doesn't matter whether it is a directory or file

Comment: But i need some more explanation

Comment: If I remove InputData folder that I created by hand then above code doesn't work. Why it doesn't automatically generate InputData folder?

Comment: That's a different question, and the answer is "because `os.mkdir` doesn't create the parent folders of the directory". You asked python to create `InputData/hc`. If no `InputData` folder exists, it can't do that.

Comment: try this : this is for  Python ≥ 3.5,  https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.mkdir  (this can invoke mkdir -p)

Answer (score 0):

The use of `os.path.exists` is redundant for your purpose because you can simply catch the `FileExistsError` exception from `os.mkdir` instead if the target directory/file does already exist:

```
for hc in list:
    try:
        os.mkdir('InputData/'+str(hc))
    except FileExistsError:
        pass
```

It would also help eliminate the possibility of a race condition if you ever run several threads or processes of this code block.

Comment: I think it should be os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
import os

list =[1.0,2.0]
for hc in list:
    if not os.path.exists('InputData/'+str(hc)):
        os.makedirs('InputData/'+str(hc),exist_ok=True)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question _"[what is] the significance of os.path.exist"_.